# add auto number 1 2 3 4 5 6 in php

Tags: php

I want to add autonumbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 to use them in the HTML tags

```
    for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
       $formattedNumber = sprintf('%02d', $i);
       $formattedNumber;

    } 

    $slug = "" . $formattedNumber;
    return '<a href="#'. $slug .'"><h'. $hTag .' id="' . $slug . '">' . $title . '</h'. $hTag .'></a>';
```

is not work It uses a fixed number for all operations

i want output

```
<h1 id=#1
<h2 id=#2
<h2 id=#3
```

this code is work but random number i want number 1 2 3 4 5 6 without duplication

```
      for($i = 1; $i <= 99; $i++) {
       $formattedNumber = sprintf('%02d', $i);
       $formattedNumber = rand(1,5);

    }

   $slug = "" . sanitize_title_with_dashes($formattedNumber);
```

Are there any solutions?

Comment: mind the `}`  -  ```for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {$formattedNumber = sprintf('%02d', $i); $slug .= "" .$formattedNumber;}```

Comment: you are looping through, overwriting the value each time. So you'll only ever get the last number

Comment: Just move the last two lines inside your loop. Right now they are running after the loop has finished. Of course, after the loop has finished, the value of $formattedNumber is fixed (as the last value assigned to it) and does not change.

Comment: Define "all operations".  This code creates exactly *one* and *only one* HTML link.  What number do you expect to see in that *one* link and why?

Comment: i want id for every operation <h2 id=#1 <h3 id=#2 <h3 id=#3

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help you but it will create a single link:

```
$slug="";
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $slug .= '<h'. $i .' id="#' . $i . '">' . $i . '</h'. $i .'>';
} 

echo '<a href="#">'.$slug.'</a>';
```

Comment: outpot is fixed number
i want id for every operation 
<h2 id=#1
<h3 id=#2
<h3 id=#3